# RewriteRule makes OAuth authorization to fail

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-rewrite, oauth

I use RewriteRule on server A to redirect to server B.
If i send a request directly to B, the authorization is OK, but if i send the request to A, which redirects to B, the autorization fails.

The RewireRule is:

```
RewriteRule ^somePath/(.*)$ http://some-server-address/main/$1 [L]
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following rewrite rule (notice the QSA):

```
RewriteRule ^somePath/(.*)$ http://some-server-address/main/$1 [QSA,L]
```

It will work only for GET requests however... POST is quite tricky